# Which graphics card to buy, DDR3 or GDDR5?

Tags: graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card, intel-graphics, graphics, ddr3

Computer Specs:

- Motherboard:    Intel DH61HO
- Processor:      Intel i3-2120 CPU 3.30Ghz
- Power supply:   450W power supply
- RAM:            Hynix 6GB DDR3 (4+2) 1333Mhz
- SSD:            Kingston SATA 240GB
- HDD:            Seagate SATA 1TB

I can only afford to buy a GT 710 or similar AMD graphics card.

I have found ASUS graphics card providing 4 years warranty but they have DDR3 and GDDR5. The GDDR5 has a fan and is cheaper also.

So my question is which is more compatible with the system configuration. **DDR3 or GDDR5?**

Also, is GT 710 2GB worth it when I already have an **Intel HD Graphics 2000**.

The problem I am facing now is that my screen flickers and freezes and I have to reset pc, losing the work I am doing. That is the reason I am thinking of buying a Graphics card.

Please help me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Graphic cards don’t use DDR3

Comment: Gigabyte GeForce GT 710 2GB DDR3 Memory Graphics Card (GV-N710D3-2GL). I know graphics card has a separate processor and memory. I don't know is I see a lot of Graphics like this and also GDR5. That's why I'm confused.

Comment: [I am pretty sure these cards are identical](https://www.gigabyte.com/Comparison/Result/3?pids=5819,6296,7063)

Comment: Then I guess the question is irrelevant. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question is answers by Ramhound as “These cards are identical”.

The sellers in Amazon are posting the ads wrong.
Ramhound said “Graphics cards don’t use DDR3”.

I finally purchased the newer card from Asus.